# Using "to" after "should"

Tags: modal-verbs

I saw some people use "to" after "should", like

> You should to install this program

But I was taught to use "should" without "to"

> You should install this program

Are they wrong or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“You should to install this program” sounds like some sort of immigrant dialect. A native speaker would not use the *to*. There is a large group of English verbs which often preceed an infinitive without *to*. The most similar to your example would be *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, and *must* (but not *ought*, which requires *to*). But consider these: *Help* me carry this; *Let* me explain; *See* Spot run; *Watch* him go. I realize that in all of those examples a noun or pronoun interrupts the series, but still they illustrate that in some very short and common idioms we drop *to* from infinitives. And sometimes a less common synonym requires *to*. For example, instead of *letting* someone explain, we can *allow* him *to* explain. Instead of *making* me stop, you can *force* me *to* stop. (Or you can try.)